# Neo4j - Iterate for common nodes for a given list of nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have no idea of iterating on list in neo4j. Please some one suggest the idea for the below problem.

Example:
 I have some nodes in the graph.
 Then, I will give few(always varying, this is the user input) keywords to search for nodes which are common to this words. In my graph each word is a node.

```
Ex: Input: [Best sports car]
output: connected nodes for Best are [samsung,porshe,ambassdor,protein,puma]
        connected nodes for sports are [cricket,racing,rugby,puma,porshe]
        connected nodes for car are [porshe,ambassdor,benz,audi]
Common nodes to all words are : [porshe]
Result is : porshe
```

I don't have any idea of iterating each word and storing the match results. Please some one suggest any idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to test the following working query, I'll make some assumptions :

- The words nodes have the label `:Word` and the `name` property.
- The porsche, puma, etc.. nodes have the label `:Item` and a `name property`.
- `Item` nodes have an outgoing `CONNECT` relationships to `Word` nodes

Which will give the following graph :

[image]

The query is the following (in order to simulate the given words as parameters, I added a WITH containing the words list in the beginning of the query)

```
WITH ["car","best","sports"] as words
MATCH (n:Word)<-[:CONNECT]-(i:Item) 
WHERE n.name IN words
WITH i, count(*) as c, words
WHERE c = size(words)
RETURN i
```

And will return only the `porsche` Item node.

**Logic explanation**

The logic of the query, is that **if** a node matches **all** given words, there will be 3 patterns to it found in the first `MATCH`, so the `count(*)` will have a value of `3` here for the `porsche` node.
This value is compared to the `size` of the `words` list.

**More explanations**

In the `WITH` statement, there is two expressions : `i` and `count(*)`.

`i` is not an aggregate function, so it will act as a grouping key.
`count(*)` is an aggregate function and will run on the `i` bucket, calculating the aggregate values.

For example, if you want to know how many words each `Item` is matching you can simply do :

```
WITH ["car","best","sports"] as words
MATCH (n:Word)<-[:CONNECT]-(i:Item) WHERE n.name IN words
RETURN i.name, count(*)
```

Which will return this :

[image]

You can see that `porsche` is matching 3 words, which is the `size` of the given `words` list, then you can simply compare the `3` from the count `aggregation` to this `size`.

In order to fully understand how aggregation works, you can refer to the manual : http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-aggregation.html

You can test the query here :

http://console.neo4j.org/r/e6bee0

If you pass the words as parameters, this will then be the corresponding query :

```
MATCH (n:Word)<-[:CONNECT]-(i:Item) 
WHERE n.name IN {words}
WITH i, count(*) as c
WHERE c = size({words})
RETURN i
```

assuming {words} is the name of the given query parameter

Comment: This is bit tricky to understand. Can you please elaborate the query.

Answer (score 1):

Is something like this what you are after?

Start with a collection of words form the requested search.

Match each word against the graph.

Collect the connected words in a list.

```
with ['Best', 'sports', 'car'] as word_coll
unwind word_coll as word
match (:Word {name: word})--(conn_word:Word)
return word,collect(conn_word)
```